# How to avoid blocking the asyncio event loop with looping functions

Tags: multithreading, websocket, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI with WebSockets to "push" SVGs to the client. **The problem is:** If iterations run continuously, they block the async event loop and the socket therefore can't listen to other messages.

Running the loop as a background task is not suitable because each iteration is CPU heavy and the data must be returned to the client.

Is there a different approach, or will I need to trigger each step from the client? I thought multiprocessing could work but not sure how this would work with asynchronous code like `await websocket.send_text()`.

```py
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def read_websocket(websocket: WebSocket) -> None:
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()

        async def run_continuous_iterations():
            #needed to run the steps until the user sends "stop"
            while True:
                svg_string = get_step_data()
                await websocket.send_text(svg_string) 

        if data == "status":
            await run_continuous_iterations()
        #this code can't run if the event loop is blocked by run_continuous_iterations
        if data == "stop":
            is_running = False
            print("Stopping process")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI runs api-calls in serial instead of parallel fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion)

Comment: Someone has kindly sent this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion
But I'm not sure what to make of this. For instance, if I place run_continuous_iterations into run_in_threadpool it will throw the not awaited error because run_continuous_iterations is async. I'm not sure how this can be solved with threading

Comment: Perhaps I need to run the websocket with run_in_executor so it has it's own thread and then manage it from there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "...each iteration is **CPU heavy** and the data must be returned to the
> client".

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), a "coroutine suspends its execution only when it explicitly requests to be suspended", for example,  if there is an [`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865050/is-await-in-python3-cooperative-multitasking) call to an asynchronous operation/function; normally, to non-blocking `I/O-bound` tasks such as the ones described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#asynchronous-code) (**Note**:  FastAPI/Starlette runs `I/O-bound` methods such as reading `File` contents in an external threadpool, using the `async` `run_in_threadpool()` function, and `await`s them; hence, calling such `File` operations from your `async def` endpoint, e.g., `await file.read()` won't block the event loop—have a look at the linked answer above for more details). This, however, does not apply to **blocking** `I/O-bound` or `CPU-bound` operations, such as the ones mentioned [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#is-concurrency-better-than-parallelism). Running such operations inside an `async def` endpoint **will block** the event loop; and hence, any further client requests will get blocked until the blocking operation is completed.

Additionally, from the code snippet your provided, it seems that you would like to be sending data back to the client, while at the same time listening for new messages (in order to check if the client sent a "stop" msg, in order to stop the process). Thus, `await`ing for an operation to be completed is **not** the way to go, but rather executing that task in a separate thread or process (if this is a CPU-bound task)—as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), but without `await`ing it—should be a more suitable way (**Note:** processes have their own memory, and hence, sharing websocket connections among multiple processes would not be natively feasible—have a look [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4199) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71090906/17865804) for available options on that). Solutions on using a separate thread are given below.

### Using `asyncio`'s [`loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) with the *default* [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)

Passing `None` as the *executor* argument in `loop.run_in_executor()`, the default executor will be used, which is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) for more details and the difference between using the default executor and a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` (as shown later on in this answer).

```py
from fastapi import WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
import asyncio

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    is_running = True
    await websocket.accept()
    
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()

            async def run_continuous_iterations():
                while is_running:
                    svg_string = get_step_data()  # synchronous/blocking function
                    await websocket.send_text(svg_string)
                
            if data == "status":
                is_running = True
                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: asyncio.run(run_continuous_iterations()))

            if data == "stop":
                is_running = False
                print("Stopping process")
                
    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        is_running = False
        print("Client disconnected")
```

### Using  `asyncio`'s `loop.run_in_executor()` with a *custom* `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```py
import concurrent.futures

#...  rest of the code is the same as above

@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    # instantiate the ThreadPool
    app.state.pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
def shutdown_event():  
    # terminate the ThreadPool
    app.state.pool.shutdown()
     
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    #...  rest of the code is the same as above
    try:
        while True:
            #...  rest of the code is the same as above

            if data == "status":
                is_running = True
                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                loop.run_in_executor(app.state.pool, lambda: asyncio.run(run_continuous_iterations()))

            #...  rest of the code is the same as above

    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        #...  rest of the code is the same as above
```

##### Update

Note that `startup` and `shutdown` event handlers have been deprecated and might be completely removed in the future. Thus, one should rather use the recently introduced `lifespan` event handler to instantiate the `ThreadPoolExecutor` at application startup and save it to `request.state`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) and the linked answer above. The `request.state`, in the case of `websockets`, can be accessed using `webscoket.state`, as shown below. You can adjust the number of worker threads as required (see the linked answer above for more details on `ThreadPoolExecutor` and the maximum/optimal number of threads).

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import concurrent.futures


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):    
    pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
    yield {'pool': pool}
    pool.shutdown()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    #...  rest of the code is the same as above
    try:
        while True:
            #...  rest of the code is the same as above

            if data == "status":
                is_running = True
                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                loop.run_in_executor(websocket.state.pool, lambda: asyncio.run(run_continuous_iterations()))

            #...  rest of the code is the same as above

    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        #...  rest of the code is the same as above
```

### Using `threading`'s [`Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

```py
import threading

#...  rest of the code is the same as above
                
if data == "status":
    is_running = True
    thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: asyncio.run(run_continuous_iterations()))
    thread.start()

#...  rest of the code is the same as above
```