# FastAPI - should I log asynchronously?

Tags: python, logging, io, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a python web application written using FastAPI (running via uvicorn). In my app I'm using the standard `logging` module which uses `TimedRotatingFileHandler`. Since I'm logging into a file I'm concerned about performance. Lets say I have 3 log messages in a function which is called with every call to a `/test` endpoint. Now imagine 1000 clients requesting `/test` at the same time - that is 3000 writes to the log file.

I'm concerned this will hinder the app's performance since IO tasks are time consuming. Should I use some form of asynchronous logging? Maybe open a new thread which will write into the file? I tried googling for answers but I found no standardized approach to it. So is it even needed? If yes, how should I approach this? Thanks!

Comment: My2cts, avoid premature optimization. Is your API too slow for you needs ? Is it too slow because of logging. If not don't over-optimize it.

Comment: Also 1000 calls to a single instance of your application is going to be difficult to scale anyways. Ideally you would scale horizontally with multiple instances of your web application on different VMs/containers to achieve higher throughputs.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804), which uses a [`background task`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) for logging the data (hence, logging takes place after a response is returned). If you need to start a new Thread inside the `background task` function, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804). Note: Asynchronous doesn't mean multithreading. Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) to understand the concept of `async`/`await`.

Comment: i tried the aiologger tool, it seemed to help quite a bit, allowing more connections per second

Comment: this article could give you an idea https://medium.com/@dresraceran/implementing-async-logging-in-fastapi-middleware-b112aa9c0db8

Answer (score 1):

In my company, the server(around 2k req/s) that we work by default logs the request and response payload, and about 2-3 more logs depending on the type of request. Of course it is somewhat of a hinderance, but unless you really need to squeeze every bit of performance, chances are there are other areas that will bring much more improvement.

Aiologger can be a solution, but if you're writing to a file it blocks anyway so look out for that.

Answer (score 0):

Like what we are doing is writing the log in the logger file when the API hits. Now let's say we have 3 logs in an API and 1000 users per second hit that API, so 3000 logs per second get generated, and writing the file doesn't take much time it is just negligible so after several seconds, we process that file i.e. uploading on the AWS Cloudwatch, which doesn't affect the API response time.