# Callback async function with FastAPI (websockets)

Tags: python, async-await, callback, fastapi, stable-diffusion

*Disclaimer:* I am new to python so I aplogize if (some parts of) the question sound(s) stupid.

---

I am trying to make an python API which utilizes [Stable Diffusion Pipelines](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion/overview).

The process of generating the result images takes about ten seconds. For User Experience purposes I am trying to relay back the current state (see example gif) to the user via websockets (byest/base64).

[Example Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw6Cf.gif)
[Source](https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/issues/3579)

The Pipeline calls a `callback` function every n (e.g 10) steps (assume the generation process takes 100 steps every time)

*the process gets iniitiated and handled via a "/ws" Websocket Endpoint from FastAPI*

##### How can I use async websocket functions in the sync image generation process?

I've tried using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to start the callback function inside a seperate thread with

- `asyncio.create_task()`
- `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor()`

but I didn't get it do work :/

Here's my current code:

**NOTE:** The callback function gets called internally by the Pipeline with the arguments:  `step: int`, `timestep: int`, `latents: torch.FloatTensor`

```py
@router.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    prompt = await websocket.receive_text()
    if(prompt == ""):
        return await websocket.send_text("Error: Empty prompt")

    def callbackCaller(iteration, t, latents):
        asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, pipelineCallback, iteration, t, latents)

    async def pipelineCallback(iteration, t, latents):
        print("called task...")
        with torch.no_grad():
            latents = 1 / 0.18215 * latents
            image = stableDiffusionPipeline.vae.decode(latents).sample

            image = (image / 2 + 0.5).clamp(0, 1)

            # we always cast to float32 as this does not cause significant overhead and is compatible with bfloa16
            image = image.cpu().permute(0, 2, 3, 1).float().numpy()

            # convert to PIL Images
            images = stableDiffusionPipeline.numpy_to_pil(image)

            # check if batch size is 1
            image = mergeImageIfNecessary(images)

            # convert to bytes
            buffer = io.BytesIO()
            image.save(buffer, format="PNG")
            buffer.seek(0) 

            # send image to client
            await websocket.send_bytes(buffer.read())
            

    try: 
        torch.Generator("cuda").manual_seed(0)

        with torch.autocast("cuda"):
            images = stableDiffusionPipeline(
                prompt=prompt,
                width=512,
                height=512,
                num_inference_steps=100,
                guidance_scale=8,
                callback=functools.partial(await pipelineCallback),
                callback_steps=10,
                num_images_per_prompt=1  # batch size
            ).images

        image = mergeImageIfNecessary(images)

        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()

        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(buffer, format="PNG")
        buffer.seek(0)

        image = buffer.read()

        if(image == None):
            return await websocket.send_text("Error: Image generation failed.")
        
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        image.save("test.png")
        image.save(buffer, format="PNG")
        buffer.seek(0)
        image = buffer.read()

        
        await websocket.send_bytes(image)
        print("closing socket...")
        await websocket.close()
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Error: {str(e)}")
    finally:
       pass
```

**Internal callback function type**

```py
callback: Optional[Callable[[int, int, torch.FloatTensor], None]] = None
```

I've read through countless stackoverflow questions and documentations but I can't get it work.

I don't understand quite how this is/could work(ing).

I've tried using several asyncio functions to respond to the user in seperate threads. I hoped to archive async handling so no error gets thrown.

Error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'websocket_endpoint.<locals>.pipelineCallback' was never awaited`

I also tried to simply await the function in the `callback` argument from the pipeline.

Error: `TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) helpful

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your quick answer. I implemented the first solution you provided:

`loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: asyncio.run(pipelineCallback(...)))`

It seems to be working just fine on the first call. In the second iteration of the function, it gets called and the websocket call executed. It does not send the data to the client on execution tho... After the completetion of the entire process, all "queued???" messages get emitted to the client. I have't found a solution to send all responses in order in "sync" via the pipeline callback. Do you know why this happes?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) as well

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for your patience with me :), I'm not sure on wether my approach with websockets is the right one. I've actually tried StreamingResponses (with the basic example from FastAPI docs) before but I didn't get it to work with my usecase, thus i switched to websockets which now also proves tricky. Before I continue with the project, I would like to settle on one specifc way to go but I'm not sure which one yet... I know it's much to ask and not really in the scope of my original question, but can you recommend what the best approach for my project would be. Best Regards ~Julian