# Call async function from sync inside async FastAPI application

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

Not sure, that this is possible, but still

I have default async FastAPI application, where I have sync function

```
@classmethod
def make_values(
        cls,
        records: list,
        symbol: str = None,
) -> list:
    values = []
    for record in records:
        new_row = SomePydanticModel(
            timestamp=record._mapping.get("time"),
            close=record._mapping.get("close"),
            value=record._mapping.get("value"),
        )
        if symbol in EXTRA_SYMBOLS:
            new_row = split_row(new_row, symbol)
        values.append(new_row)

    return values
```

The problem is that `split_row` is async function, that calls other async functions

```
async def split_row(
        row,
        symbol,
):
    adjusted_datetime = datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime("01/01/19", "%m/%d/%y"))
    splits = await get_splits(symbol)
    # some big part with business logic with other async calls
    return row
```

Currently I get coroutine in `new_row` variable. Is there anyway to get the result of split_row?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), in order to better understand the concept of `async`/`await` and how FastAPI/Starlette works under the hood.

Comment: One way to do this is to use `loop.run_in_executor()` and run the `async` function using `asyncio.run()` in a separate Thread, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804). Still, I would highly suggest thoroughly reading the linked answer above.

Comment: As your code stands, `values` is a list of coroutines.  Instead of declaring `make_values` async def, you could pass `values` up the call stack until you reach an async function.  Unless `make_values` is a callback, there must be an async function somewhere up the stack (since you have a running event loop).  You could then await the list of `values` at that point.  No matter what you do, *somewhere* you *have to* await each element of `values`.  Because `split_row` is async, it cannot return a meaningful result without yielding to the event loop at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event loop to run the asynchronous function.

```
import asyncio

@classmethod
def make_values(cls, records: list, symbol: str = None) -> list:
    values = []
    for record in records:
        new_row = SomePydanticModel(
            timestamp=record._mapping.get("time"),
            close=record._mapping.get("close"),
            value=record._mapping.get("value"),
        )
        if symbol in EXTRA_SYMBOLS:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            new_row = loop.run_until_complete(split_row(new_row, symbol))
        values.append(new_row)

    return values
```

Comment: Nope. `RuntimeError: this event loop is already running.` The code is already running in async FastAPI application

Comment: Oh, Yes. Because fast API is already managing the event loop. Then maybe you can try to make the make_values method asynchronous.

Comment: yeah, seems like it's the only working idea:( I'm just asking, maybe there is any other way

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be using [Asyncer](https://asyncer.tiangolo.com/) (which is on top of Anyio) introduced by Sebastian Ramirez the creator of the FastAPI. In the documentation, there's a section ["Call Async Code from Sync Code"](https://asyncer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/syncify/).

Here's the use case:

> ```py
> import time
> import anyio
> from asyncer import asyncify, syncify
>
> async def do_async_work(name: str):
>     await anyio.sleep(1)
>     return f"Hello, {name}"
>
> def do_sync_work(name: str):
>     time.sleep(1)
>     message = syncify(do_async_work)(name=name)
>     return message
>
> async def main():
>     message = await asyncify(do_sync_work)(name="World")
>     print(message)
>
> anyio.run(main)
> ```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- As an advantage, it's also possible to use `asyncio.run(main())` instead of `anyio.run(main)` at the end.