# How to run two blocking functions concurrently?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have two blocking functions, I want them to stay separate, in separate threads or tasks.

```
def foo():
# This can run as a background process
    while True:
        # do something
        # write to disk
    return data

def bar():
    # read from the disk that was generated by foo
    # do something
    return data
```

Foo and bar are methods in different classes in different files.

I have a fastapi web socket server.  I want both functions to start running and keep running, concurrently at the same time, as long as the client hasn't disconnected or as long as the client hasn't sent a `STOP` command.

`bar()` function is supposed to keep running and scanning the disk. Every time I receive data back from `bar()`, I should send it back to the client via `await websocket.send_text(data)`

I tried running them in a pool or using a queue but `foo` would prevent `bar` from starting.

I can make both of them async, but that's not ideal, because I'd have to store a lot of data in memory rather than on disk since reading from disk isn't easy when working with async functions. Besides, the logic works well, there's no need to introduce async.

If I were to do that I would have to remove the reading from the disk part and store the data in a shared dictionary for each websocket client.

I tried doing that, but I'm facing two issues:

1. The dict stays empty when bar() tries to read from it, not sure how to share data between the two functions
2. I don't like asyncio because it often gets stuck and can't stop it when a stop command is  sent or when the client disconnects.
3. I didn't use fastapi background tasks to run `foo` because fastapi background tasks cannot be stopped on demand.

One of the versions I tried

```
@app.websocket("/live-transcription")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    client_id = id(websocket)
    tasks = []

    stop_event = asyncio.Event()

    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            message = json.loads(data)
            command = message.get("command")
            url = message.get("url", "")
            if command == "STOP":
                stop_event.set()
                if tasks:
                    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
                stop_event.clear()
                tasks.clear()
                if client_id in FILE_STORAGE:
                    del FILE_STORAGE[client_id]

            elif command == "START":
                FILE_STORAGE[client_id] = {}

                bar_task = await asyncio.create_task(
                    bar(client_id, stop_event)
                )

                foo_task = await asyncio.create_task(
                    foo(url, client_id, stop_event)
                )

                tasks = [bar_task, foo_task]

            while tasks and not websocket.closed:
                while True:
                    try:
                        response = await bar_task.result()
                        if response:
                            await websocket.send_text(response)
                        else:
                            break
                    except asyncio.CancelledError:
                        break 

            # Clear finished tasks
            tasks = [t for t in tasks if not t.done()]
            if client_id in FILE_STORAGE:
                del FILE_STORAGE[client_id]

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print("Client disconnected")
    finally:
        for task in tasks:
            task.cancel()
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        if client_id in FILE_STORAGE:
            del FILE_STORAGE[client_id]
        await websocket.close()
```

Comment: if you are using `asyncio` then you want to "gather" the tasks (for parallel) otherwise you want to "await" (for series).  The `threading` module might be a bit simpler to use in the sense that it does not require async functions.

Comment: Either `threading` or a ThreadPool; the former if you want all the threads to run as needed, the latter if you want up to _n_ threads to run at any one time (to manage the load)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: @Chris yes I used a similar approach,  loop.run_in_executor() with the default ThreadPoolExecutor and the issue was solved

Answer (score 0):

if you dont like `asyncio` as stated in the question (which i agree with, but for other reasosn), then you can use the `threading` module like this:

```py
import threading
import time

def foo():
    while True:
        # do something
        print("foo is writing to disk")
        # simulate writing to disk
        time.sleep(1)  # simulate some work and release control
        # write to disk

def bar():
    while True:
        # read from the disk that was generated by foo
        print("bar is reading from disk")
        # simulate reading from disk
        time.sleep(1)  # simulate some work and release control
        # do something

# Create threads for foo and bar functions
foo_thread = threading.Thread(target=foo)
bar_thread = threading.Thread(target=bar)

# Start the threads
foo_thread.start()
bar_thread.start()
```

which returns this:

```
bar is reading from disk
foo is writing to disk
foo is writing to disk
bar is reading from disk
foo is writing to disk
bar is reading from disk
foo is writing to disk
```

One disadvantage of threading is that the user has less control over when the threads occur (they just take the next available place). But i have never personally had an issue with this.

Comment: The're's still a missing part here. I aim to do `while True: data = foo_thread await websocket.send(data)`

I have to send data to the user on each foo run

Comment: `await` is compatible with `asyncio` and not `threading`, so would need to pick one or the other.